# How to grant exception to Content-Disposition attachment?

Tags: .htaccess, content-disposition

I used this code in .htaccess to force all files to download --

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

However, how can I grant an exception to index.php for it not to download. I know that FilesMatch can be used but I need all files to download except index.php. I can't possible list out all the file extensions in FilesMatch. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can negate in `FilesMatch` directive:

```
<FilesMatch "(?!index\.php).*">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```